Power switching module works on paper but not in real life
I have created a power switching module for the purpose of manually swapping power sources to a flight computer FC. NC and NO are both inputs, where any battery connected to NC powers the FC when both GPIO inputs are unpowered.
When both GPIO inputs are pulled high (by an MCU), power is removed from NC and instead flows to FC from NO. I have found that my schematic already has a few issues, for one the pulldown resistors for Q2 and Q3 should go to the Source pin instead of what I have labeled as "ground."
Another issue is that I believe a positive voltage component makes way through the body diode of either mosfet if the battery has a low internal resistance and the voltages on each battery is different. To mitigate this I added diodes in series with each power source to block current in the opposite direction.
In the printed PCB I have added external 10K pulldowns in the correct location and used diodes on each power supply, however the whole circuit still seems pretty non-functional. Connecting two power supplies, one to NC and one to NO, and then adding a load to FC results in current normally flowing from NO, and by shorting the two logic outputs to NC ground, I can get current to flow through the NC power supply.
I have also simulated this circuit using falstad. The circuit can be found here. In the simulation it appears to work as intended, so I am confused as to what is causing my issues with the printed board. I have done basic checks on all components and they are all rated for my voltage/current.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks


In the falstad circuit the switches are connected to the always available +12 of FC, but in the shown circuit the signals TP1 and TP2 are relative to the switched GND of FC, which will not work the same.

Hello,
Post printing I had moved the resistors to properly ground to the source pin of each MOSFET, I have updated the schematic to reflect the printed (non-working) version. When you say that the signals are relative to the switched GND of FC, was that what you meant or am I misunderstanding something?
Thank you.

Cite link to image.

Measure and annotate all voltages

By labelling two different nodes "PWR_FLAG ", you are implicitly connecting them together. I'm pretty sure you didn't intend to short-circuit 0V and +12V in this way, but that's what you've done. Also, why have you used a gate driver for Q2, but not for Q1?

Examine the scenario where both NO and NC have a voltage source connected, Q2 is switched fully on, but Q1 is off. Here's a simplified representation, with everything unimportant removed:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If there's 0.6V or more difference in source voltages, \$V_{NO}-V_{NC} \ge 0.6V\$, the body diode of Q1 is strongly forward biased, and will pass a lot of current, even though Q1 is supposed to be off. You say you mitigated this with diodes:

simulate this circuit
That works to reduce Q1 current to zero, so the only remaining suspects are Q3 and its peripheral resistors:

simulate this circuit
Q1 and R3 now provide a loop around which current can flow through source \$V_{NC}\$. That has the side effect of raising the potential at Q1's source, which forward biases its body diode, and starts conducting, still with Q1 completely off.
Unfortunately, unless you consider or simulate all possible conditions before you build, you'll miss little quirks of behaviour like this, and reality bites you. I'd like to say this is easy to fix, and perhaps what I'm about to suggest will work for you, but I can't guarantee it because I won't test it under all possible conditions. My proposed fix is to move diode D1 to a new home at Q1's drain (and do the same for D2):

simulate this circuit
Q3 still has power from source \$V_{NC}\$, but D1 isolates the entire left side, preventing Q1's body diode from ever becoming forward biased.
A word of warning: both MOSFETs' on/off state depends on the potential difference \$V_{GS}=V_G-V_S\$. In other words, Q1 and Q2 are switched on or off by changing \$V_{GS}\$, not just \$V_G\$. Since the sources of both transistors are free to rise and fall in potential, you can't say with certainty that a standard MCU logic level \$V_G\$ will successfully switch on or off the respective transistor. Perhaps it will, I haven't examined all possible scenarios, but you should take care with this.
Another potentially much greater problem can arise if signals from FC are fed to other parts of a different sub-system sharing the same ground:

simulate this circuit
FC is permanently tied to +12V, so when FC's low-side switches are open, all nodes of FC will have +12V potential too, such as FC's "OUT" terminal above. You do not want to apply those 12V to any other input of any other device on the system, for obvious reasons.
Most (if not all) of these problems are related to the use of low-side switching of power to FC. FC's ground node is not permanently held at 0V, and you can no longer rely on potentials anywhere (even Q3's source) to be 0V. To guarantee that potentials everywhere have a known and controlled potential relative to 0V ground, usually we tie the ground nodes of every interconnected sub-system permanently together, so that they all have the same idea of what 0V is, always, and communicate with each other using signals that are sure to have appropriate potentials.
By making a ground connection "optional" for any single sub-system, we have to take extra care to ensure that this doesn't cause grief for everyone else.
That's not to say that high-side switches don't have their issues. They do, such as "phantom powering" of sub-systems that are supposed to be off, via their inputs connected to sub-systems that are powered. Making an unconditional common ground alleviates many headaches, but not all of them.

Your Falstad simulation has errors in drawing.  Wrong values for FET Beta and have 8V drop at 1A, with 12V/2 ohms=6 A or 3A each is expected.
Ground is missing so node voltages have no 0V reference. The label does nothing.
When low RdsOn (Beta =10) applied, the FETs may get fried with no current limit shorting batteries to each other if both are enabled and voltage difference with high capacity.
The 3rd FET serves no purpose other than to invert switch logic.
No design specs being offered is the biggest problem.
